# Redirects & Google Indexing

Tags: redirect, indexing

I have a website I've designed for a client here: http://www.haniabyanyacole.com

I'm using a meta http-equiv="refresh" to redirect the user from the splash page to haniabyanyacole.com/site/ (I know that's not recommended) and I think this is causing Google to return the first search result for the company's name with http://haniabyanyacole.com/site instead of the root directory.

Is there a redirect solution (301, 302?) that will force Google to index the root instead of /site/?  FYI I have uploaded a sitemap to Google Webmaster Tools that includes haniabyanyacole.com/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a META HTTP-EQUIV, which google equates to a redirect response header, you can try using javascript to do the redirect for you, on a delay. Maybe something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function redirect_to_site(){
    window.location = "http://haniabyanyacole.com/site"
}
//-->
</script>
```

in your page header, then in the body tag add:

```
onLoad="setTimeout('redirect_to_site()', 10000)"
```

so that it looks something like:

```
<body onLoad="setTimeout('redirect_to_site()', 10000)" >
```

This will redirect to `http://haniabyanyacole.com/site` after 10 seconds.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I will try your method and let you know how it works.

Comment: I tried this method and it's been about a week and the top search result is still /site/.  Are there any other methods that might work?